# update a vector using assign in R

Tags: r, vector, append, paste, assign

I am implementing k-means in R. 
In a loop, I am initiating several vectors that will be used to store values that belong to a particular cluster, as seen here:

```
    for(i in 1:k){
    assign(paste("cluster",i,sep=""),vector())      
    }
```

I then want to add to a particular "cluster" vector, depending on the value I get for the variable getIndex. So if getIndex is equal to 2 I want to add the variable minimumDistance to the vector called cluster2. This is what I am attempting to do:

```
minimumDistance <- min(distanceList)
getIndex <- match(minimumDistance,distanceList)
clusterName <- paste("cluster",getIndex,sep="")
name <- c(name, minimumDistance)
```

But obviously the above code does not work because in order to append to a vector that I'm naming I need to use assign as I do when I instantiate the vectors. But I do not know how to use assign, when using paste, when also appending to a vector.

I cannot use the index such as vector[i] because I don't know what index of that particular vector I want to add to.

I need to use the vector <- c(vector,newItem) format but I do not know how to do this in R. Or if there is any other option I would greatly, greatly appreciate it. If I were using Python I would simply use paste and then use append but I can't do that in R. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: basically the R way to do this is to create a list where the list elements correspond to all the cluster objects you currently create. It is then straightforward to append to each list element.

Comment: Thank you very much @mts -- I am putting the vectors into a list and it seems to work this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
out <- list()
for (i in 1:nclust) { 
   # assign some data (in this case a list) to a cluster
   assign(paste0("N_", i), list(...)) 
   # here I put all the clusters data in a list
   # but you could use a similar statement to do further data manipulation
   # ie if you've used a common syntax (here "N_" <index>) to refer to your elements
   # you can use get to retrieve them using the same syntax
   out[[i]] <- get(paste0("N_", i)) 
}
```

If you want a more complete code example, this link sounds like a similar problem [emclustr::em_clust_mvn](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/emclustr/blob/master/R/clust_mvn.R)